# Obtener cuantas veces aparece un ID en otra tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla "clientes" que contiene los datos de clientes y otra "amigos" que contiene los datos de amigos invitados por un cliente. Quiero mediante un Select obtener el correo de los clientes que han invitado a un multiplo de 5 amigos.

Tengo algo asi, pero no me funciona

```
 SELECT id_clientes, email 
 FROM clientes WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM amigos WHERE id_clientes = id_clientes) % 5 = 0;
```

¿Alguien podria Ayudarme? Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `mod` en una combinación con la función `count`, al conteo total de amigos de un cliente, le calculas el residuo de dividirlo por 5. Para poder utilizar estas funciones como criterio de búsqueda, tienes que utilizar la [cláusula having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

```
select a.id_clientes, a.email
from clientes a, amigos b
where a.id_clientes = b.id_clientes
group by a.id_clientes
having mod(count(a.id_clientes),5) = 0
```

Comment: Funciono excelente, Muchas gracias